# Java ImageIO: can't read input file

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, javax.imageio

I don't know why this isn't working, but the program says it can't read the input file. This is also being run in Ubuntu, by the way:

Here is the sample code:

```
URI url = new URI("images/GUI/TitleScreen.PNG");
File file = new File(url.toString());           
bg = new ImageBackground(ImageIO.read(file));
```

The directory is located in the bin folder and src folder of the program as well.

Comment: What's with the complicated `URI`->`File` thing? Why not just open the file?

Comment: If relative path doesn't work, try to use absolute path. If this still doesn't work, check the current directory of the application process using `System.getProperty("user.dir");` and compare it with the path of the image file

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem because of that. It can't find the right directory of the images, apparently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you instead got your image as a stream from a resource?  e.g.,

```
String imgPath = "images/GUI/TitleScreen.PNG";
BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgPath));
bg = new ImageBackground(buffImage);
```