# Creating a buffered image in Java, can't read input file error

Tags: java, image, file, bufferedimage, japplet

I'm making a JApplet and attempting to create a buffered image in java, then to draw subimages of it on each half of the screen (this is a 2 player game).

The Declaration is:

```
public File map = new File("Resources/fullmap.png");
public BufferedImage fullmap;
```

fullmap.png is the Image of the entire map I'm using and it's in my resources folder.

I then try to initialize the BufferedImage and create the subimage by doing this:

```
try { 
            fullmap = ImageIO.read(map);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tankgame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Image drawP1Side = fullmap.getSubimage(p1.x, p1.y, w/2, h/2);
```

However I get an error that says "Can't read input file". Am I initializing my file "map" incorrectly? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is Can't read input file then it can be problem with your image path.
Try using

```
public File map = new File("/Resources/fullmap.png");
```

Comment: @user2739431 have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251633/java-imageio-cant-read-input-file)

Answer (score 0):

The java docs state that inside an applet, you have to do something slightly different:

> If the code is running in an applet, then its just as easy to obtain
>   the image from the applet codebase. The following excerpt is from
>   LoadImageApplet.java:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "Resources/fullmap.png");
    fullmap = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tankgame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Hmm sorry to hear that, can you give us the full directory of the main file and the image, eg : MyFile.html MyFile.java Resources/fullmap.png?